# Send Http request to sharepoint is returning this error "The property '__metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.ResourcePath"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I want to move custom list items between identical lists i followed those links:-

https://gist.github.com/zplume/9f4c1a658517802701deff3473f23a60

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN_Jr8GW64g

So i created this flow:-

[image: johnjohn123_0-1690415723335.png]

but i will get this error:-

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The property '__metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.ResourcePath'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."}}}
clientRequestId: 71cf6fce-73bd-4335-83df-31ae603dd853
serviceRequestId: 816ccaa0-d0d5-6000-ff29-594c711f7947
```

any advice?

Answer (score 1):

In action "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" change Header "Content-Type" from

> application/json; odata=nometadata

to

> application/json; odata=**verbose**